# Android App: Architecture for app with AppBar, BottomNavigation and CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I am currently developing an Android app where I need to have the following components : an AppBar at the top, a BottomNavigationView and a framelayout that contains the fragment behind pushed with a transaction. All of this must be inside a coordinator layout so that the AppBar and Bottom Bar get hidden when scrolling.

Everything works fine for the top levels fragments, which are lists, but when I click on one item of those lists, I push a new fragment, which can have several features different from the first one, such has a CollapsingToolbarLayout, or a FAB button on the bottom right. Those new components should also follow the scroll and get hidden / replaced, but as they are not direct children of the CoordinatorLayout, they dont get any event. How should this kind of solution be handled ?

I'm juste trying to follow material design best practices with keeping the bottom bar everywhere, hiding it etc, but I cant get it working with fragments.